Modal Window Close Button Complications
The problem I am currently experiencing is that my modal window is not closing when I press the close button in the popup window. The goal of my program is that when you click on a "booth," a window will pop up with a header, a description, and two options. Depending on what you submit, it will lead to another action.
I have tried multiple options, but I am stuck on this seemingly simple task. Below is my current code:


document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    function closeModal() {
        const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
        modal.style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('modal-body').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('file-upload').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('submission-confirmation').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('upload-btn').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('file-input').value = '';
    }

    const closeBtnHeader = document.getElementById('close-btn-header');
    if (closeBtnHeader) {
        closeBtnHeader.addEventListener('click', function() {
            closeModal();
        });
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
        const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
        if (event.target === modal) {
            closeModal();
        }
    };

    document.querySelectorAll('.interactive-area').forEach(function(area) {
        area.addEventListener('click', function() {
            if (!this.classList.contains('no-popup')) {
                const boothId = this.id;
                const dimensions = this.getAttribute('dimensions');
                showModal(boothId, dimensions);
            }
        });
    });

    function showModal(boothId, dimensions) {
        const modal = document.getElementById('modal');
        document.getElementById('modal-header').innerText = "Details for " + boothId;
        document.getElementById('booth-info').innerText = "The dimensions are " + dimensions + ".";
        modal.style.display = "block";
    }

    document.getElementById('submit-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        const selectedOption = document.querySelector('input[name="booth-option"]:checked').value;
        const modalBody = document.getElementById('modal-body');
        const fileUpload = document.getElementById('file-upload');
        const submissionConfirmation = document.getElementById('submission-confirmation');

        if (selectedOption === 'option1') {
            modalBody.style.display = 'none';
            fileUpload.style.display = 'block';
        } else if (selectedOption === 'option2') {
            modalBody.style.display = 'none';
            submissionConfirmation.style.display = 'block';
        }

        storeReservationRequest(selectedOption);
    });

    document.getElementById('file-input').addEventListener('change', function() {
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
        const uploadBtn = document.getElementById('upload-btn');
        const fileError = document.getElementById('file-error');

        if (fileInput.files.length > 0) {
            uploadBtn.disabled = false;
            fileError.style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            uploadBtn.disabled = true;
        }
    });

    document.getElementById('upload-btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('file-input');
        const fileError = document.getElementById('file-error');

        if (fileInput.files.length === 0) {
            fileError.style.display = 'block';
        } else {
            const files = fileInput.files;
            for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                console.log('Uploading file:', files[i].name);
            }
            alert('Files submitted!');
            closeModal();
        }
    });

    const closeBtn = document.getElementById('close-btn');
    if (closeBtn) {
        closeBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            closeModal();
        });
    }
});

function storeReservationRequest(selectedOption) {
    const userEmail = localStorage.getItem('userEmail');
    const reservationRequests = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservationRequests')) || [];
    const newRequest = {
        user: userEmail,
        status: 'Request Submitted',
        option: selectedOption,
    };

    reservationRequests.push(newRequest);
    localStorage.setItem('reservationRequests', JSON.stringify(reservationRequests));
    alert('Reservation request submitted!');
    window.location.href = 'reservationStatus.html';
}
<!-- Modal -->
<div id="modal" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" aria-label="Close" id="close-btn-header">&times;</button>
        <h2 id="modal-header">Booth Details</h2>
        <div id="modal-body">
            <p id="booth-info">Details about the selected booth will appear here.</p>
            <div id="booth-options">
                <p>Please choose one of the following options:</p>
                <label><input type="radio" name="booth-option" value="option1"> Submit your own documentation for booth layout.</label><br>
                <label><input type="radio" name="booth-option" value="option2"> Use the standard layout provided by the expo.</label>
            </div>
            <button id="submit-btn" class="modal-submit">Submit Request</button>
        </div>
        <div id="file-upload" style="display: none;">
            <p>Please upload your documentation per your request.</p>
            <input type="file" name="file" id="file-input" accept=".pdf,.doc,.docx,.ppt,.pptx,.png,.jpg,.jpeg,.gif" multiple />
            <p id="file-error" style="color: red; display: none;">Please select at least one file to upload.</p>
            <button id="upload-btn" class="modal-submit" disabled>Upload Files</button>
        </div>
        <div id="submission-confirmation" style="display: none;">
            <p>Your request has been submitted.</p>
            <button id="close-btn" class="modal-submit">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
         




Check the console. You have a syntax error
